# Video is not played in iOS project

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, media-manager

I have used Plugin.MediaManager in my Xamarin.Forms application. It works perfectly in Android project, but in iOS project it does not.

I have added

```
VideoViewRenderer.Init();
```

in AppDelegate, and this is the code in the view:

```
    async void PlayStop_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BtnPlayStop.Text == "Start Video")
        {
            string video = Path.Combine(_videoPath, this.viewModel.Item.Video);

            if (File.Exists(video))
            {
                await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(video, MediaFileType.Video);

                this.BtnPlayStop.Text = "Stop Video";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await CrossMediaManager.Current.Stop();

            this.BtnPlayStop.Text = "Start Video";
        }
    }
```

Code enters the first if, since button changes its text to 'Stop Video' but no video appears. The video is a local mp4 file.

As I told, this works perfect in Android.

What's wrong?

Thanks

Jaime

Comment: Have you tried wrapping this line "await CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(video" inside an invokeonmainthread. The event is called on a separate thread that causes the video to play but not on the main UI thread

Comment: That code is in the shared project. Will that work in Android too?

Comment: Review the device|simulator log for AVKit warning/errors produced by the AVPlayer.

Comment: @SushiHangover it is not the log I already posted? What is that log and how to get it? I am with Visual Studio 2019 for Mac.

Comment: Yes it should work on both, did it work?  Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
{
CrossMediaManager.Current.Play(video, MediaFileType.Video);});

Comment: @jstuardo You have not posted any log... https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/enhanced-device-logging-in-visual-studio/

Comment: @Saamer it did not work. No video started playing.

Comment: @SushiHangover this is shown in the log: Error (351) / MyApp.iOS(CFNetwork): NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002. I am not sure that call is generating that error.

Comment: I have  added file:// before the actual video path, and the problem was solved.

Comment: @jstuardo Hi , if have solved , remember to share slution in answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced the method that plays or stops the video by this one:

```
    async void PlayStop_Clicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.BtnPlayStop.Text == "Iniciar Video")
        {
            string video = Path.Combine(_videoPath, this.viewModel.Item.Video);

            if (File.Exists(video))
            {
                Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() =>
                {
                    _ = CrossMediaManager.Current.Play("file://" + video, MediaFileType.Video);
                });

                this.BtnPlayStop.Text = "Detener Video";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            await CrossMediaManager.Current.Stop();

            this.BtnPlayStop.Text = "Iniciar Video";
        }
    }
```

The "file://" part is important when loading local media files.

With that method, it works in both Android and iOS.

Regards
Jaime

Regards
Jaime